How do I refocus the camera away from the boss during the fight in X2: Wolverine's Revenge?
In X2: Wolverine's Revenge (2003), during the boss fight (Juggernaut), Wolverine can keep running and move freely until the first attack. After that, he faces the enemy, and I can't make Wolverine run away. Staying close to the enemy makes all the moves clumsy.
Changing the controls did not help. There are two options for camera movement.
